# Laravel Passport: Create access token manually

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm trying to find a way to create an access token manually in Laravel 5.5 using Passport and can't seem to figure it out.

I have 2 applications, one that holds the frontend and one api. The user receives an invitation via mail, and when he accesses the link, i wish to create the auth token and send it back in the response.

Any ideas on how to do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Solved it myself. It seems that the [HasApiTokens](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/5.0/src/HasApiTokens.php#L64) trait that you put on the users model has a method to create a token

```
$user->createToken($name, $scopes);
```

Comment: It don't seems to, it's a fact and described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport (search for _createToken_)

Comment: Note that according to the docs: Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not modified when using the tokensExpireIn or refreshTokensExpireIn methods.